# How can I get the same result as using curl -i option, with using python requests module?(JSONDecodeError)

Tags: curl, python-requests, hdfs

I'm creating a file on HDFS with REST API.
https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.1.2/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/WebHDFS.html#Create_and_Write_to_a_File

Following the document, when I try with curl command, everything works well.

```
➜  ~ curl -i -X PUT 'MY_HDFS_URL?op=CREATE&overwrite=true' -H 'Authorization: AUTH_INFO'
HTTP/1.1 307 Temporary Redirect
Date: Mon, 29 Jun 2020 05:07:17 GMT
Server: SERVER
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache
Expires: Mon, 29 Jun 2020 05:07:17 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
X-FRAME-OPTIONS: SAMEORIGIN
Location: WHAT_I_NEED_TO_KNOW
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Length: 0
Set-Cookie: BLAHBLAH
Set-Cookie: BLAHBLAH
Set-Cookie: ROUTEID=.1; path=/
```

But when I try to do the same thing with python code, it doesn't show the above information.

```
>>> r = requests.put(url='MY_HDFS_URL?op=CREATE&overwrite=true', headers=hdfs_headers)
>>> r
<Response [201]>
>>> r.text
''
>>> r.json()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 898, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Why is this happening??

Why can't I get the response date when using requests?

Any thought appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

I had to get response headers.

https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#response-headers

Instead of `r.json()` or `r.text`,

```
r.headers
```